# In Dynamics CRM 2011, what would keep the contact form related ribbon tab from displaying

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

So something happened and the related ribbon tab ("add") is mising on contact and opportunity. It's still there on Account. Any ideas what could make this tab disappear. The XML for contact has nothing. I currently have no javascript running on form load. I am so lost as to what could cause this.

Comment: What do you mean with "The XML for contact has nothing"? Is there any customization regarding the ribbon?

Comment: Are you accessing the form as a System Administrator or another security role? Could be related to permissions.

Comment: I am System Administrator. Look slike it might be a bug. Working with MS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a problem with your security role.  You should check the Contact permissions and compare with Account.  I think the permission you need to look for is named "Append To".